# PHP Shows up as blank

Tags: php

I'm not a PHP expert but I'm just getting blank when I put my code into blogger and wordpress.

I've checked everything several times and am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've even tried downloading PHP plugins for wordpress. Nothing.

```
$url = "https://api.footystats.org/league-tables?key=example&league_id=1625";
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$league = json_decode($json, true);
print_r ($league['data']['all_matches_table_away']);
```

I've deleted the PHP opening and closing tags for this post, because the code doesn't show for some reason here either.

I need it to show the English Premier League table. I've made the table no problem but it shows no elements within it.

Comment: Your PHP snippet works fine, the problem should be in somewhere else. Please enable PHP report to view the actual error message.

Comment: I am using wordpress HTML though, how do I enable PHP report there? (I am just doing this for a simple code I partnered with, I am not an expert)

Comment: in your config file set define(wp_debug, true)  and see what error php throughs.